# Php data to Html table dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php file that set an array of values and a table into a html page. I would like to insert the php data into this table with a limit 15 of rows so when the data reaches the limit, continue on an adjoining table:
[image: Tables structure]

Could JQuery be a good option to get this?.

Comment: yes its a good option. you need to use ajax to use the php script to echo back the data -- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Yes. Create a loop inside a table for each row of data in your PHP script. Inside each loop create a table row for each set of data you want to display.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if those data change dynamically, using jQuery would be a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

i believe it would be faster, if you directly divide it using php.
here is a piece of code for your problem.

```
//assuming this is your database retrieval
$tableArr   = array();
for($i=1; $i<=50; $i++) {
    $tableArr[] = '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td> Name '.$i.'</td><td> Type'.$i.'</td></tr>';
}
//chunked or divided data
$dividedArray   = array_chunk($tableArr, 15);
$dataTable      = "";
$commonHeader   = '<thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Type</th></tr></thead>';
foreach($dividedArray as $indDividedTable) {
    $dataTable.= '<table border="1">';
    $dataTable.= $commonHeader;
    $dataTable.= implode("\n", $indDividedTable);
    $dataTable.= '</table>';
}
echo $dataTable;
```

Comment: this is probably the easiest approach since he literally wants multiple tables...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you mean by "adjoining" literally "next to it" but I've used jQuery Datatables for pagination of data and it has worked out well.  You may want to modify your PHP to output the data into a JSON format, or perhaps even make the data-fetch a separate query back to the server.

Comment: Yes,two tables are in same page. I am searching in web and i have found what you advise me regarding the conversion of data into json. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What does adjoining means? If you mean pagination, jQuery surely can do this using AJAX. I'm using jQuery plugin [datatables](http://datatables.net/)
to retrieve data from PHP with JSON format. It has table pagination by default.

Comment: It is a split table in two or three depending on page width. I have converted my php data into json using `json_encode($data1[$i])` and 
I think using this [link](http://michaeleisenbraun.com/columns/) i could create the table dynamically.
Thanks.